# ActiveModel::Serializer not allowing me to load serializer in app/serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have the following api controller in ('app/controllers/api/v1/companies_controller.rb'):

```
class Api::V1::CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    companies = Company.all
    render json: companies, serializer: CompanySerializer
  end
end
```

but the above is looking for Api::V1::CompanySerializer in `app/serializers/api/v1/company_serializer.rb`. I'd rather just have a generic company serializer in `app/serializers/company_serializer`. I have tried using the scope resolution operator like:

render json: companies, serializer: ::CompanySerializer

but still getting an error.  How would I tell my controller to use the default serializer explicitly? I have seen this issue https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1701 and, if this is the ONLY behavior allowed, it seems like a strange choice

[image]

Comment: Have you tried what [this](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1701#issuecomment-213263900) comment says?

I use the other module nesting syntax and the serializer (in `app/serializers` is picked up without needing to explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 1):

[AMS 0.10.7 **Implicit Serializer** vs **Explicit Serializer**](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.7/docs/general/rendering.md)

You really don't need to pass any serializer option as long as your serializer has the default name. So `render json: companies` should work.

Explicit way would look like:

```
render json: companies,
  serializer: CollectionSerializer,
  each_serializer: CompanySerializer
```

Note: The default serializer for collections is `CollectionSerializer`. In your example, you tried to pass `CompanySerializer` to `serializer`.